# Sticky top Bootstrap Div fixed scroll

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use `sticky-top` of bootstrap to set a div when I scroll, I have tried the following:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="sticky-top">
     <app-reserva></app-reserva>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have read similar questions where they say that you have to add the following:

```
.sticky-top { top: 0.5em; }
```

But this did not work for me either, what am I missing?

Comment: Please describe your problem in english

Comment: It would be helpful if you make a working demo for SO community to look into it

Answer (score 1):

IE11 and IE10 will render position: sticky as position: relative. As such, we wrap the styles in a @supports query, limiting the stickiness to only browsers that can render it properly.Use below class in div and also you may have to use some more css to specify the position of the div

```
<div class="sticky-top">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.col-md-4 {
  height: 1000px;
  background: black;
}

.sticky-top {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="sticky-top">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```